# Display loading message while third party website is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am displaying price offers for flights obtained via a third party service. When the user clicks one of the prices, he is redirected to another website for booking the flight. The problem is that the booking page loads very slowly on the other website. Is there a way to display a popup message while the booking page is loading in the same window? Or somehow preload the booking page and display it only when it's fully loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can put an `alert('message')` in `$(document).ready()` function if you are using jQuery .This would display the alert pop-up after the page has been loaded.